# Detect usb device name automatically on connection

Tags: linux, bash, cp

When I am trying to copy directory from Linux home directory to usb drive(pen drive), In the case of following command `cp -r /home/directoryname /media/usbname(pendrivename)` it is working fine.

But I am looking the command , copy the directory with out giving "usbname(pendrivename)"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have understood your demand, but if I have a script like this should do the trick if your USB drive is always monted with the same tag :

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r $1 /media/usbname(pendrivename)
```

If you save the script as `~/cpusb.sh`, you can do :

```
chmod cpusb.sh
echo "alias cpusb=cpusb.sh" >> .bash_aliases
source
```

and then use `cpusb` when you want.

Comment: in shell script cp -r $1 /media/usbname(pendrivename) its work for any pendrive or only specific one.

Comment: You have to replace `usbname(pendrivename)` by the tag of your USB device. If it is classicaly partioned, the tag is fixed. You can modify it using a tool such like gparted.

Comment: When you use the USB drive, what is its name ? Its mount point should be `/media/name` or `/media/user/name`, depending on your distribution. You simply put this mount point in the script *if* the name of the USB drive is fixed. If it is not, the mount point would be a random string, so you can easily see that.

Comment: @Shan-x No need for the alias there - just drop the `.sh` suffix from your script. Having to maintain both a script and an alias that points to the script is needlessly complex.

Comment: But what if he wnts to use it from another directory ?

Comment: @Shan-x Then that alias won't work, anyway, unless the location where the script is stored is in one of the directories listed in `$PATH`. And if it's in one of those directories, the alias still accomplishes nothing. Just name the script `cpusb`, put it in `${HOME}/bin/`, and make sure `$PATH` contains `${HOME}/bin`, and it should just work...

Answer (score 0):

I think i'd use `mount` to textually infer the connected usb's dir using `sed` or `awk`.

Maybe even save `mount`'s result when nothing is connected and 'subtract' it from `mount`'s result after connecting a new usb device.

Or even better, run your script **before** you connect the device:
- the script will run `mount` every second and will wait for a change in the result.
- when a change is detected, the newly added device is your usb.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount_old="$(mount)"
mount_new="${mount_old}"

while [[ "${mount_new}" == "${mount_old}" ]]; do
    sleep 1
    mount_new="$(mount)"
done

# getting added line using sort & uniq
sort <(echo "${mount_old}") <(echo "${mount_new}") | uniq -u | awk '{ print $3 }'

# another way to achieve this using diff & grep
# diff <(echo "${mount_old}") <(echo "${mount_new}") | grep ">" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

It's merely a sketch, you might need/want to refine it.